# "Cannot resolve method" with mockito

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

I use `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` which has a method:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

I want to mock it as below:

```
when(authentication.getAuthorities()).thenReturn(grantedAuthorities);
```

with authorities collection:

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = Lists.newArrayList(
        new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));
```

And I am using `org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority` which extends `GrantedAuthority`

And Intellij gives me below compile error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(java.util.Collection<org.spring.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority>)'
```

I use Mockito `2.15.0` and `thenReturn()` method from it is:

```
OngoingStubbing<T> thenReturn(T value);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try using the other syntax to return your collection with a wildcard matching generic: 
`doReturn(grantedAuthorities).when(authentication).getAuthorities();`

This `doReturn` call isn't type-safe and results in a runtime check on type but for your purposes it will return the mocked list you want.

There are a lot of details using mockito and generics with wildcards. For more details:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Wildcards

Comment: lovely trick! it has solved a couple of other errors on my tests as well! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ensure type safety you can initialize your collection as

```
 Collection grantedAuthorities =
 Lists.newArrayList(
         new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.USER));
```

Then you can normally use `when(authentication.getAuthorities()).thenReturn(grantedAuthorities);`

The advantage with this solution is that `grantedAuthorities`'s type is preserved.

For more details check [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/mocking-method-with-wildcard-generic-return-type).

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @voutsasg was critical to solving a similar issue of mine, because the `doReturn` solution only deferred the exception to runtime.

Given:

```
List<SfingeId> sfingeIds = List.of(sfingeId1, sfingeId2, sfingeId3)
```

Where: `SfingeId implements ElementId`

The following code snippet

```
Map<SfingeId, Integer> numberOfOccurrences = Map.of(
        sfingeIds.get(0), 10,
        sfingeIds.get(1), 20,
        sfingeIds.get(2), 30
);
when(someDataProvider.countNumberOfOccurrences(sfingeIds)).thenReturn(numberOfOccurrences);
```

produced the same error as above:

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(...)
```

---

My solution was simply to use the interface instead of the concrete class that implements it:

```
Map<ElementId, Integer> numberOfOccurrences = Map.of(
        sfingeIds.get(0), 10,
        sfingeIds.get(1), 20,
        sfingeIds.get(2), 30
);
when(someDataProvider.countNumberOfOccurrences(sfingeIds)).thenReturn(numberOfOccurrences);
```

This solved the issue (at runtime as well).