# Why am I getting "method thenReturn undefined" with Mockito 3 for methods without wildcard types?

Tags: java, mockito

The following code gives the compiler error: `The method thenReturn(null) is undefined for the type FrequencySummary` on the starred line:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import edu.mills.cs180a.wordnik.client.api.WordApi;

public class SimpleTest {
    private WordApi mockWordApi = mock(WordApi.class);

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        when(mockWordApi.getWordFrequency(anyString(), "true", anyInt(), anyInt())
            .thenReturn(null); // *** COMPILER ERROR ON THIS LINE
        when(mockWordApi.getWordFrequency("apple", "false", 2000, 2001))
            .thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

I understand that [Mockito gives this error for methods with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168430/cannot-resolve-method-with-mockito); however, the signature of `WordApi.getWordFrequency` is:

```
FrequencySummary getWordFrequency(@Param(value="word") String word, @Param(value="useCanonical") String useCanonical, @Param(value="startYear") Integer startYear, @Param(value="endYear") Integer endYear)
```

There is another version of the method that has parameterized types, but that has a different parameter count and no wildcards:

```
FrequencySummary getWordFrequency(@Param(value="word") String word, @QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, Object> queryParams)
```

As you can see, there are annotations in the method declarations. Does that break `thenReturn()`?

The class `WordApi` was generated by Spring and Swagger for Feign. I am using Java 15 with Mockito 3.6.0.

Comment: Your `"true"` should at least be wrapped in a matcher like `eq`, that should read something like `eq("true")`. Everything should be matchers, or direct values not a mix of both.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, I will make that change. For anyone reading this, that did not fix the problem.

Comment: It also looks like you are missing a `)` after `anyInt())` . Which leads to calling `thenReturn` on your mocked `WordApi` instead of the Mockito mocking API.

Comment: That was it! Do you want to make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well I'd rather close this with a reason of a typo, because that was actually what was going on.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure of the difference between closing and deleting. I'll delete it if you recommend doing so, but I was thinking it would be useful to keep it around so someone who made the same mistake could find the solution.

Comment: I just put in a vote to close it. Let's see how it goes. Generally, a compiler error is due to typos or not having included the proper dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

On the starred line , you are missing a closing parenthesis `)` after

> anyInt())

As a result `thenReturn` is called on your mocked `WordApi` instead of the Mockito mocking API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).